# Track link clicks with generated jquery on my site, used on other people sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been searching everywhere for a solution but can't find one...

I have a jquery generator for affiliates(my users) that automatically ads an image with his target url at the end of a video, that i need to track the links in a wordpress database.

**Process map:**
Generated Jquery code from my site with target link -> User puts code on his site -> User visitors click on target content from his site -> I track those clicks using jquery so i can show to my user how many people clicked his ad.

My question is how can i track simply the number of clicks to the target content from an external site that has my jquery code on it?

Thank you, and i hope my answer can help others as well that have a similar issue like me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we use at my work place is an image tag 1px width and 1px height. You can put in the `src` attribute of the image the link to a PHP script which adds the click event in the database.

So the jQuery will look like this:

```
$('.ad').click(function(){
    $(this).append('<img src="http://somesite.com/tracking.php?ref=code" width="1" height="1">');
})
```

And **tracking.php** should look like this:

```
<?php
  // connect to database
  // insert in database click for site with refferal $_GET['code']


  // code for returning the image
  $img=imagecreate(1,1);
  $color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
  imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);
  header("content-type:image/jpg");
  imagejpeg($img);
  imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast and awesome solution, i'll start to implement and see how it goes :)

Comment: Also added the code to return the image with the proper header.

Comment: FYI This method is typically called "Image Beacons". Google for more info.

Comment: We just call it the _tracking pixel._